# Interesting Geometry Problem. The Converse is easy.

Tags: geometry

Chords $AC$ and $DB$ intersect at $G.$ In Triangle $AGD$ the altitude from $G$ meets $AD$ at $E$ and extended meets $BC$ at $P$ so that $BP = PC.$ Prove $AC$ perpendicular to $BD.$

Comment: If I show that GP = CP and BP, then it is proven. I cannot see how yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is not necessarily true. Observe the following image:

[image]

As you can see, all of your givens are true, but $AC$ is not perpendicular to $BD$.

Comment: You are correct. I missed that. Thank you. The problem comes from Challenging Problems in Geometry by Posamentier Problem 4.4 Converse.

Comment: [link] (https://www.google.com/search?q=challenging+problems+geometry+pdf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @MichaelLevine Ah, I own that book. :)

Comment: @MichaelLevine No worries. If you found my answer helpful, just $\uparrow$ and $\checkmark$!